# C++ Receiving error that the function was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, arrays, function, sorting

This is the porgram I am writing for my university's Assignment. I have written all the codes that takes 10 integers from user, and asks user to press 1 to show odd integers in ascending order from the list or 2 to show the even integers in ascending order from the list.

Well, I have declared and defined the Bubble Sorting function before the main() function in program, and used the function later in main() to sort the even and odd numbers in ascending order. But, I am still getting the error that the function was not declared in this scope even when I have declared it at the top. I tried all possible things I could do. Kindly help me what should I do? Below is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

void BuubleSort_Function(int [], int);

void BuubleSort_Function(int arr[], int arrSize)
{
    int extraMem;

    for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
    {
        for(int arrIndex = 0; arrIndex < arrSize - 1; arrIndex++)
        {
            if(arr[arrIndex] > arr[arrIndex+1])
            {
                extraMem = arr[arrIndex];
                arr[arrIndex] = arr[arrIndex+1];
                arr[arrIndex+1] = extraMem;
            }
        }
    }
}

main()
{
    int num[10], i, even[10], odd[10], inputOpt, totalEvens = 0, totalOdds = 0;

    system("cls");

    cout << "Please enter 10 integers: " << endl;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cin >> num[i];
    }

    cout << endl << endl << endl << "1. Show odd numbers in ascending order and their total numbers" << endl;
    cout << "2. Show even numbers in ascending order and their total numbers" << endl;

    do
    {   
        cout << endl << "Enter 1 for the first option or 2 for the second option: ";
        cin >> inputOpt;

        if(inputOpt != 1 && inputOpt != 2)
        {
            cout << "Wrong Input! Please enter the correct input value";
        }
    }
    while(inputOpt != 1 && inputOpt != 2);

    if(inputOpt == 1)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if(num[i] % 2 == 1)
            {   
                odd[totalOdds] = num[i];
                totalOdds++;
            }
        }

        BubbleSort_Function(odd,totalOdds);
        cout << endl << "The total numbers of Odds Integers are " << totalOdds;
        cout << endl << "The Integers arranged in Ascending Order:" << endl;

        for(i = 0; i < totalOdds; i++)
        {
            cout << odd[i] << "\t";
        }
    }

    if(inputOpt == 2)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if(num[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                even[totalEvens] = num[i];
                totalEvens++;
            }
        }

        BubbleSort_Function(even,totalEvens);
        cout << endl << "The total numbers of Odds Integers are " << totalEvens;
        cout << endl << "The Integers arranged in Ascending Order:" << endl;

        for(i = 0; i < totalEvens; i++)
        {
            cout << even[i] << "\t";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't define your `main` to return an `int`?

Comment: @AndyG is it necessary to define `main` as `int`? I thought it is not necessay and C/C++ automatically consider it as `int`

Comment: No, that's incorrect. You need to write `int main`. What the compiler does do automatically is insert an implicit return 0 if it's missing.

Comment: The standard dictates that you must declare the return type as `int` (§3.6.1 [basic.start.main])

Comment: @AndyG and @Bathsheba thanks, I will correct and declare the `main` functions as `int`

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar: You're hired! (Note that `main` is the *only* function for which a compiler inserts an implicit `return 0;` if necessary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple typo: the function is declared and implemented as `BuubleSort_Function`.

You attempt to call it using `BubbleSort_Function`.

The compiler error messages are very helpful. Do learn to interpret them.

(Finally, standard C++ requires you to mark `main()` as returning an `int` - a C++ compiler will insert an implicit `return 0` into `main` if it's missing. Some compilers - especially ones for embedded systems - drop this requirement but that is a deviation from the standard.).

Comment: I did not understand, I am new to programming, can you please elaborate? Should I call the function by different name and not the name which I used to declare/define it?

Comment: Can you not see that you've misspelt "Bubble"?

Comment: Oh i got it now. thank you so much. Lol I did not even notice that I misspelled it :D

Answer (score 1):

Defination - **BuubleSort_Function**

Caller - **BubbleSort_Function**

Answer (score 1):

Compare the 5th line and the 7th line with the 64th line,and you will find what the problem is.Just a simple typo.

Comment: Upvoted for counting the lines! (I assume you did that accurately).

Comment: I just put the codes into DevCpp and figured out the lines.
Thanks for upvoting!